# Gcloud How could i set compute engine have multiple user and each of them use other ip addresses

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine, xfce

Hello guys I am using google cloud compute engine , i chose linux debian 10 for my VM and install xfce desktop and chrome remote based on this guidance

```
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine
```

Now i would like to install 1 more xfce desktop to this VM(maybe other user) and set it to use other static ip address then is there any way to do it ?
Thank you guys so much

Comment: You can assign multiple IP addresses to your VM instance accordingly to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding). Unfortunately, there's no way to connect users and IP addresses. What is the goal you're trying to reach?

Comment: I'm trying to utilizing power of my vm. I created 1 vm with 2vcpu and 4 gb of ram. And just used 50% of this instance. So instead of creating new vm i would to install 1 more xfce desktop to existing vm and assign other ip to this desktop.  Due to some reason i would like to use other user on this vm to run my script ( selenium script).  Thank you so much

Comment: Okay, but why do you need other IPs for other users? Why don't you just add more users or change machine type to get less resources?

Comment: I need other ip for crawling data and it's just 1 web browser tab . So proxy is the best solutions but i don't have. And the minimum flavor is 2 vcpu cores. I just need 1 and abit higher ram for smooth operation

Comment: You can use [free tire](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute) `f1-micro` VM instance for free for your proxy. Will it solve your problem?

Comment: "the minimum flavor is 2 vcpu cores" Where do  you have this limitation?